# React useRef render count increases from 1 to 3 on the first change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using useRef to track the render count in a React functional component. However, I noticed that when the component re-renders for the first time, the render count increases from 1 to 3 instead of 2. I'm wondering why this is happening and how I can fix it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
const UseRef = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const renderCount = useRef(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        renderCount.current = renderCount.current + 1;
    });

    return (
        <>
            <input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
            <div>My name is {name}</div>
            <div>I rendered {renderCount.current} times</div>
        </>
    );
};

export default UseRef;
```

Comment: This is caused by [Strict Mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#strictmode) and only in development.  It's meant to [help you find bugs](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development) that cause memory leaks in your app.

Comment: Above beat me to it, Strict Mode in App.js causes a double re-render, you can see the results by temporarily removing and re-evaluating the console to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

this will do it

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  
    <App />
 
);
```